# webdriverio: allure open command is starting the server but webpage is not loading

Tags: cucumber, reporting, webdriver-io, allure

I am trying to generate allure report by using cmd [allure generate --clean reports/allure-results]in webdriverio
***Steps followed:***
https://webdriver.io/docs/allure-reporter/
I am able to see allure-report folder generated

[image]

when I am running allure open command its showing

[image]

But when web browser launching , its showing error as below

[image]

**package.json**

```
 "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.6.2",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.12",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.16.12",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.12",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.16.11",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.11",
    "chromedriver": "^97.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
```

I hope I have provided enough details, please let me know if you need any other info

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Finally, I found that the default host and port opened by Allure were not allowed from my Mac machine. So I set it up with localhost and port 8081, then it successfully launched the browser and showed the report. Command is : `allure open -h localhost -p 8081`

Answer (score 0):

Double-check you have the `allure-commandline` package installed.
Also is `allure-results` in your root directory or under `reports/`? Make sure that matches your configuration in your `wdio.conf.js` file.

Assuming there is **not** a `reports/` directory, this would be your command to run to generate the report and open it: `allure generate --clean allure-results && allure open allure-report`

If there is a `/reports` directory: `allure generate --clean reports/allure-results && allure open allure-report`

Answer (score 0):

- Run allure command line npm install -g allure-commandline
- Then generate report allurer-report allure generate --clean allure-results && allure open allure-report